# Image in Tkinter lower right corner issue; need it full and centered

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

**I fixed it by adding anchor='nw' to the line button.config line. I appreciate your help.**

I am programming a lock that takes images as input and shows the image; the picture is showing up cropped (attached). The images are 1000x1000.

Before I select an image:

[image: Before]

After I select an image:

[image: After]

The end result is this:

[image: End result]

Here is my code below

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os


# Global variables to store the selected images and hand attributes
selected_images = []
selected_hands = []

def select_image(button_index):
    file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("JPEG files", "*.jpg")])
    if file_path:
        # Load the selected image and update the corresponding button with the new image
        image = Image.open(file_path)
        image.thumbnail((150, 150))  # Resize the image to fit within a 150x150 box
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
        buttons[button_index].config(image=photo)
        buttons[button_index].image = photo  # Keep a reference to the image

        # Read the hand attributes from the "combo.txt" file based on button_index
        combo_file = "library/lock/combo.txt"
        with open(combo_file, "r") as file:
            # Read the lines from the file and get the hand attributes for the current button_index
            hand_attributes = file.readlines()[button_index].strip().split()

        selected_hands.append((image, hand_attributes))


def read_expected_combination(file_path):
    # Read the expected hand attributes from the given file
    expected_combination = []
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            expected_combination.append(line.strip().split())
    return expected_combination


def check_combination(selected_hands, expected_combination):
    # Check if exactly three images are selected
    if len(selected_hands) != 3:
        return False

    # Convert the selected hand attributes to sets for comparison
    selected_attributes_sets = [set(hand[1]) for hand in selected_hands]

    # Check if any of the combinations match the expected combination
    for expected_attributes in expected_combination:
        expected_attributes_set = set(expected_attributes)
        if all(hand_attributes in expected_attributes_set for hand_attributes in selected_attributes_sets):
            return True

    return False

def check_lock():
# Read the expected combination from the "combo.txt" file
    combo_file = "library/lock/combo.txt"
    expected_combination = []
    with open(combo_file, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            expected_combination.append(line.strip().split())
    
    if check_combination(selected_hands, expected_combination):
        messagebox.showinfo("Lock Status", "UNLOCKED - The lock is open!")
        lock_status.set("UNLOCK")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Lock Status", "LOCKED - The lock remains closed.")
        lock_status.set("LOCK")
    # Perform the combination check
    #if check_combination(selected_hands, expected_combination):
        #lock_status.set("UNLOCK")
    #else:
        #lock_status.set("LOCK")


# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Hand Image Lock")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=200, bg="white")  # Set the canvas size
canvas.pack()

# Create the buttons to select images
buttons = []
for i in range(3):
    button = tk.Button(root, text=f"Select Image {i+1}", command=lambda idx=i: select_image(idx))
    button.pack()
    buttons.append(button)

# Create the label to display the hand description
description_label = tk.Label(root, text="", wraplength=300)
description_label.pack()

# Create the text box to display the lock status
lock_status = tk.StringVar()
lock_status.set("LOCK")
lock_status_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=lock_status, font=("Arial", 18, "bold"), fg="red")
lock_status_label.pack()

def reset_selection():
    # Clear the selected images and hand attributes
    selected_images.clear()
    selected_hands.clear()

    # Reset the image buttons to their initial state
    for button in buttons:
        button.config(image="", text=f"Select Image {buttons.index(button)+1}")

    # Reset the lock status
    lock_status.set("LOCK")
    
# Create the button to reset the selection
reset_button = tk.Button(root, text="Reset", command=reset_selection)
reset_button.pack()

# Create the button to check the lock status
check_button = tk.Button(root, text="Check Lock", command=check_lock)
check_button.pack()

# Run the tkinter main loop
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried to pack the image and I have changed the size of the window. Neither fixed the issue.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue.  The image fills the button.  My platform is Windows 7 with Python 3.8.17.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Could you please send me a screenshot? I am on MacOS running 3.11

Comment: See [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5UCc.png).

Comment: @acw1668 I fixed it by adding anchor='nw' to the line button.config line. I appreciate your help. Maybe you could help me with other stuff.

Comment: Add module from tkmacosx import Button Then run it.

Comment: Does is worked?